# Adding multiple javascript events programmatically - no inline javascript

Tags: javascript

Adding multiple javascript events programmatically

I have successfully added a form submit event code using the following:

```
if (window.addEventListener){           
    window.addEventListener('load', attachFormSubmit, false);
}else if (window.attachEvent){
    window.attachEvent('onload', attachFormSubmit );
}
```

Now I have a textbox on the page text1 and I want to clear the value of it when it takes focus.

I tried adding the following:

```
function attachFocus()
{
    var txt = document.getElementById("text1");
    if (txt.addEventListener){      
        txt.addEventListener('focus', ClearText(txt.id), false);
    }else if (txt.attachEvent){             
        txt.attachEvent('focus', ClearText(this.id));
    }
}

    function ClearText(id)
    {
        var obj = document.getElementById(id);
        obj.value='';
    }
```

And I added a call to attachFocus to the window load event:

```
if (window.addEventListener){           
    window.addEventListener('load', attachFormSubmit, false);
    window.addEventListener('load', attachFocus, false);
}else if (window.attachEvent){
    window.attachEvent('onload', attachFormSubmit );
    window.attachEvent('onload', attachFocus );
}
```

So the code I added for the textbox focus event does not work. Can someone point out to me what am I doing wrong and also recommend a better way to add events via javascript. I do not want to use inline javascript

Comment: Have you tried using onclick instead of onfocus, and see if that works?

Comment: is jquery and option? would make this a lot easier

Comment: You've used the best method already. But, `addEventListener` expects a function as an argument, not `undefined` returned from `ClearText`. You've done this correctly for `load` though. You're also missing `"on"` from the event name in the code for IE when attaching `focus`.

Comment: I see you have `txt.id` in one place and `this.id` in another. Maybe that's the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

when you write  `ClearText(txt.id)`

you are not **passing** the function

you are **calling** the function

You should write:

```
 txt.attachEvent('focus', function() {clearText(txt.id);});
```

Or:

```
txt.addEventListener('focus', ClearText.bind(txt), false);

function ClearText() {
  var obj = document.getElementById(this.id);
  obj.value = '';
}
```

Comment: `txt` having only scope within the function attachFocus, isn't `this.id` more appropriate?

Comment: You could alternatively just do `txt.addEventListener('focus', clearText)` if you change the `clearText` function accordingly, e.g. `function clearText() {this.value='';}`.

Comment: Matt Browne, your suggestion worked for newer browsers, where I used addEventListener, but in case of attachEvent for older browsers, "this" came up as undefined in ClearText function

Comment: ShyA, When I use txt.attachEvent('onfocus', function() {ClearText(txt.id);}); the txt.id comes up as undefined

Comment: OK, I got it to work by switching txt.attachEvent('focus', function() {ClearText(txt.id);}); to txt.attachEvent('onfocus', function() {ClearText(txt);});

Comment: @ElenaDBA BTW if you want people to be notified of your responses to their comments, use the `@` symbol before their username. I happened to see your response because I still had this page open but otherwise would have missed it. Glad you got your problem resolved.